# Senggigi to Labuhan Lombok, how to?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, buses, indonesia

I plan to go from Senggigi (west Lombok) to [Labuhan Lombok](https://goo.gl/maps/btLV4) (east Lombok).

Is there any buses or shared taxi doing this journey?

If yes, where can I take it? how much is it? and how long does the journey take?

[image: Lombok island map with Senggigi & Labuhan Lombok pointed out]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Answer (score 5):

Get a bemo from Senggigi to Mataram's [Mandalika bus terminal](https://plus.google.com/113331827111760164552/about?gl=au&hl=en) (*Terminal Bis Mandalika*), from where there should be semi-regular onward bemos to Labuhan Lombok (about 2 hrs).  Prices are fixed and should be listed on the notice board at Mandalika, it was Rp. 11,000 a few years back.

Comment: I wanted to add up to date info to your question but there was too many changes, so I had to simply add my own answer. Prices seem to have gone up a lot (even though still very cheap).

Comment: No worries, and thanks for adding up-to-date info!

Comment: Hey, I created a dedicated question for Mataram's Mandalika bus terminal to Labuhan Mongol as it'll be part of something a bit bigger in the future ;) http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51357/9395 please do add any answer to it if you have time, thx

Answer (score 3):

The info below is from **2015**.

#### Senggigi to Mataram's [Mandalika bus terminal](https://plus.google.com/113331827111760164552/about?gl=au&hl=en)

In Indonesian: Terminal Bis Mandalika.

Take a Bemo:

- This takes around 30 minutes
- Price is around 15'000 IDR
- Departure times: whenever the bemo is full (or almost)

#### Mataram's Mandalika bus terminal to Labuhan Lombok

I wrote a dedicated question for this: [Mataram to Labuhan Lombok, how to?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/51357/9395)