# Where are the companies sailing from Lombok to Komodo?

Tags: indonesia, sea-travel, sailing, komodo, lombok

I would like to sail from [Lombok](https://goo.gl/maps/QnHEs) to [Komodo](https://goo.gl/maps/PzPdM).

I want to follow the advice of a backpacker I met in order to get the best possible deal: go to the harbour to **directly** negotiate with the companies running those sailing trips (vs with an agent getting a cut).

I figured they should be either in the harbours of Bangsa, Senggigi or [Mataram](https://goo.gl/maps/lrlfM).

But I could only find very little information on this topic hence my call for help.
Thanks in advance

[image: Lombok island map]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking on the wrong side of the map.  Boats to points east depart from [Labuhan Lombok](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Labuhan_Lombok) on the eastern side of the island, as clearly labeled in the map you yourself posted (!), and all travel agents and operators in Senggigi, Mataram etc ship you across there by shuttle bus before putting you on the boat.

That said, if your aim in this exercise is to cut costs, I think you're barking up the wrong tree: any direct cruise from Lombok will by definition be expensive.  The **cheapest way** to do this is to cross from Lombok (Labuhan Lombok) to Sumbawa (Poto Tano), cross Sumbawa by bus, and then find somebody going to Komodo/Rinca from Sumbawa's eastern port of Sape.

The **sane way**, though, is to [fly to Labuanbajo and start from there](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48725/what-is-the-best-way-to-see-komodo-island-leaving-from-and-returning-to-bali), and it's not going to cost much more when you figure in the cost of accommodation (and aggravation) involved in the alternative.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to fly there but everything is pretty booked up, so I'm left with the sailing option, or the bus+terry option.

Comment: Btw, the map only labeled ferries to Sumbawa, not the sailing boats. I assumed the sailing boats have a peculiar itinerary. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Oh, and it seems like I will use your other answer to get to Labuhan Lombok :) http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51165/senggigi-to-labuhan-lombok-how-to