# Mataram to Labuhan Lombok, how to?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, indonesia, lombok

I am in Idonesia, in Lombok, & I plan to go from Mataram (west Lombok) to [Labuhan Lombok](https://goo.gl/maps/btLV4) (east Lombok).

Is there any bemos, buses or shared taxi (or else) doing this journey?

If yes, what are the departure times? how much is it? how long does the journey take? where can I take it?

[image: Lombok island map with Mataram & Labuan Lombok pointed out]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Answer (score 1):

The info below is from **2015**.

Go to Mataram's [Mandalika bus terminal](https://plus.google.com/113331827111760164552/about?gl=au&hl=en) (*Terminal Bis Mandalika*).

---

#### Bemo

- It takes about 3h
- Price offered by drivers is 50'000 IDR, this may be negotiable although I asked a few different people at the station and they all mentioned the same price.
- Departure time: the bemo must be full (or almost) before it can leave so you may have to wait half an hour or so. Just jump in the Bemo that has the highest number of passengers already waiting inside.

---

#### Modern bus

- western standard type of bus welcoming around 40 people. Very comfortable: with AC, toilets on board, & big nice seats
- It takes 2h
- price is higher (not sure how much)
- buses leave at 15:00

Note that some Indonesian guy said something about a buses also leaving in the morning, but I'm not 100% sure as I never met anyone confirming thus not have I read anything confirming this either.

---

See a picture of some the Bemos below.

[image: Bemos in Mataram Mandalika bus terminal, Indonesia]